# Issue with the image resize in html

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I have added photo swipe code in my phonegap project which should be full screen swipe, but i'm able to get all images at one slide even though the demo of it is in full screen 
screen shot ouput
     [image]

here's the code

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Demo</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/idangerous.swiper.css">
  <style>
     /* Demo Styles */
  body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  }
 .swiper-container {
  width: 660px;
  height: 250px;
  color: #fff;
   text-align: center;
 }
 .swiper-slide {
  width: 500px;
   height: 100%;
  }
  .red-slide {
  background: #ca4040;
 }
 .blue-slide {
  background: #4390ee;
  }
  .orange-slide {
   background: #ff8604;
  }
 .green-slide {
 background: #49a430;
  }
 .pink-slide {
  background: #973e76;
  }
.swiper-slide .title {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 42px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  line-height: 45px;
 }
  .pagination {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 20;
   left: 10px;
   bottom: 10px;
  }
   .swiper-pagination-switch {
   display: inline-block;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background: #222;
    margin-right: 5px;
     opacity: 0.8;
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     cursor: pointer;
       }
      .swiper-visible-switch {
       background: #aaa;
      }
     .swiper-active-switch {
     background: #fff;
     }
      </style
    </head>
     <body>
    <div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide red-slide">
    <div class="title">Slide 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide blue-slide">
    <div class="title">Slide 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide orange-slide">
    <div class="title">Slide 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pagination"></div>
 </div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/idangerous.swiper-2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
pagination: '.pagination',
paginationClickable: true,
moveStartThreshold: 100
})
</script>
```

Comment: Head over to http://jsbin.com , create a demo of what you are trying to do and then ask a question that most people would at least understand.

Comment: hey thanks for your link it might be useful for me. i had tested the above demo i was getting the output correctly run in a seperate demo, but when i added it to currently running project i get this type of output @SunnyRGupta

Comment: Maybe your new project is not able to access the .css files you have referenced in the code, or such problems?

Comment: It seems there is a typo in `style` closing tag. check once.. `</style` must be `</style>`.

Comment: i have corrected still issue remains the same @Mr_Green

Comment: @DD. update your post then. I will check. BTW, `<!DOCTYPE html>` not `<!doctype html>`

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to put a `>` to your `</style` tag.